# RStudio and Shiny: define a reactiveValues with a Reactive

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I am having a dataframe that is build depending on user input, choosing different filters. I then want to create a bar plot from this custom dataframe where the user can click on to exclude bars from the plot. I basically followed this example:
https://gallery.shinyapps.io/106-plot-interaction-exclude/

However, when I try to define my reactiveValues value with my reactive, I can not define it and get an error. I am suspecting I can not define a reactiveValues with a reactive, is this right? How should I handle this then? Should I use `reactive`s instead of `reactiveValues`?

Example code:

**Server**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- reactive({
  input$input1
})

vals2 <- reactive({
   (df())
})
output$Id1 <- renderText({
   vals2()
})

vals <- reactiveValues()
vals$bla <- df()
}
```

**UI**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
  column(width= 4,
       textInput(inputId = "input1", label = "Select number of rows", value = "10")
),
   column(width = 12,
       verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "Id1"),
       verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "Id2")
  )
 )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your reactiveValues towards the beginning of your function and initialise is with a NULL

```
vals <- reactiveValues(bla = NULL)
```

You can then write to `vals$bla` from inside `observeEvent`, for instance when a button is pressed.

You can read from the reactiveValue, for instance to draw a plot in the form:

```
output$myPlot <- renderPlot( some function of values$bla )
```

EDIT updating to add my comment, create an observeEvent which watches your input1, when this changes it will execture the code within {} which will write to your reactiveValue.

```
observeEvent(input$input1, {
    vals$bla <- input$input1    
})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. My issue is that I want to assign a value from a reactive to a reactiveValue$bla. How can I do this?

Comment: what is the reactive value that you would like to assign?

Comment: As in my example, which does not make too much sense, but illustrates what I want to do. I need to assign `df()` to `vals$bla`. However, I am not sure, whether this is possible.

Comment: to assign some input value to a reactiveValue, use an observeEvent triggered by the input.